# How to select and focos part of a text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

I have a box with text, this box has a scroll.

[image]

I want to be able to tap on a button and select the text "products". If the text that I want to select is not on the screen, I need to jump into it.

[image]

Is it possible using Flutter web or desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectableText()` widget instead of normal `Text()` widget

Comment: Yeah. I'm using it. But how can I jump to parts of the text? Like a find in text (cmd f, ctrl f).